# Cannot fetch row id using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I cant fetch my db row using PDO. Currently I am using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` but my result is showing blank.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//create_cat.php
include 'dbfunctions.php';
include 'forum_header.php';

$db = getConnection();

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT
            topicid,
            topicsubject
        FROM
            topics
        WHERE
            topics.topicid = :id ";

$result = $db->prepare($sql);

$result->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$result->execute();

$numrows = $result->fetchColumn();


if(!$result)
{
    echo 'The topic could not be displayed, please try again later.';
}
else
{

    while($topicrow = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
            echo "hello";

        //display post data
        echo '<table class="topic" border="1">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th colspan="2">' . $topicrow['topicsubject'] . '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        //fetch the posts from the database
        $posts_sql = "SELECT
                    posts.topicid,
                    posts.postcontent,
                    posts.postdate,
                    posts.postby,
                    users.userID
                FROM
                    posts
                LEFT JOIN
                    users
                ON
                    posts.postby = users.userID
                WHERE
                    posts.topicid = :id ";

        $posts_result = $db->prepare($posts_sql);
        $posts_result->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $posts_result->execute();
        $posts_numrows = $posts_result->fetchColumn();

        if(!$posts_result)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>The posts could not be displayed, please try again later.</tr></td></table>';
        }
        else
        {

            while($posts_row = $posts_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<tr class="topic-post">
                        <td class="user-post">' . $posts_row['userID'] . '<br/>' . date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($posts_row['postdate'])) . '</td>
                        <td class="post-content">' . htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['postcontent'])) . '</td>
                      </tr>';
            }
        }

        if(!$_SESSION['CurrentUser'])
        {
            echo '<tr><td colspan=2>You must be <a href="signin.php">signed in</a> to reply. You can also <a href="signup.php">sign up</a> for an account.';
        }
        else
        {
            //show reply box
            echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><h2>Reply:</h2><br />
                <form method="post" action="forum_reply.php?id=' . $row['topicid'] . '">
                    <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea><br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit reply" />
                </form></td></tr>';
        }

        //finish the table
        echo '</table>';
    }
}

include 'forum_footer.php';
?>
```

After the while loop I cannot fetch my row['topicsubject'] did I missed something .Can anyone help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is being returned when you run this? Which if/else statement does it trigger? If nothing, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the very top of your file to give you any errors that may be hidden.

Comment: Sidenote: If and when you do fix this, and that you have, let's say 10 rows in there? You'll be creating 10 table tags. I doubt you want `echo '<table class="topic" border="1">';` inside that loop.

Comment: @Steve my code executes into the first else statement and the second else statement too but after the second else statement, its not working inside the while loop. I did some testing just now. So once i put my echo "test" into my while loop there is no result being shown.

Comment: Besides what @Steve said, add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Assuming you're using `$db` as your variable in your connection function. Plus, your posted code is missing a few braces, or whether that's relevant or not.

Comment: Oh, I see what's wrong here. Your conditional statements are way off. What you're doing here is your first `if` checks if there's NO results. Then your `else` and other nested `if`s to check if there NO rows etc. Re-think this.

Comment: @Steve i tried adding the code you sent me, but it is not showing any errors

Comment: I'll bet if you change `if($numrows == 0)` to `if($numrows > 0)` or `if($numrows == 1)` magic will happen. If it does, I'll make it an answer with the other comments I posted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just tried to change the the numrows >0 as you said the code executes, but once i add my while loop inside the if statement my result is blank

Comment: Or  instead just do an `foreach ($result as $row) { /*print $row..*/ }` and the no-rows check afterwards with `if (!isset($row)) { /* No topics, baby. */ }`. Alternatively use `fetchAll()` even for the exact row count.

Comment: I have no idea why you're using this also `if($numrows == 0)
    {

        echo 'This topic does not exist.';
    }` if you're doing this `if(!$result)`. Plus there's code missing what you posted, so again; not sure if it's relevant or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually i am following the book tutorial only. I am trying to learn to use pdo instead of mysql.

Comment: The almighty question now then. How is this being fetched? `$_GET['id']`. From a form? From a URL? From JS/Ajax? Plus, I noticed you're using sessions. Did you start the session?

Comment: I noticed you placed `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` under `$db = getConnection();` in your edit. That's not what I meant. That needs to be inside the file you're using that contains the DB connection credentials. I hope you are indeed using PDO to connect with, and not `mysqli_`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- from URL actually..well yes session i have started on my header file

Comment: How exactly is that URL formed? Also, you probably need to start the session for all files. I've seen that before.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is how the the url is formed `echo '<h3><a href="forum_topic.php?id=' . $row['topicid'] . '">' . $row['topicsubject'] . '</a></h3>';`

Comment: Another thing I noticed, you're doing `WHERE
            topics.topicid` then further down you have `posts.topicid` you sure about one of those tables/database? I could be wrong. But, check what your HTML source reveals in regards to what you left me above as the URL.

Comment: can we move the discussion to the chat? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Where is this? `echo '<h3><a href="forum_topic.php?id=' . $row['topicid'] . '">' . $row['topicsubject'] . '</a></h3>';` it's not in your question. Is it part of that same file? Can't move to discussion, you  don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i am sure about it, because my posts table foreign key is the topic id from topics table

Comment: @Fred-ii- no its not part of the same file, that code is from my index.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow so much debate for a small problem. Your first call to `fetchColumn()` fetches the data from the only row there is. So there is nothing left for `fetchAll()` to fetch.